# Make the edges narrower, while the middle thicker?

Tags: mesh

I'm a complete beginner in blender (started like a week ago), so sorry if it is a completely noob question. I have the following 'cylinder', I would like to create a bike crankset from it. What I want to achieve now is to make the teeth narrower, while giving a little bit of thickness at the middle (It would proportionally get thicker). How can I achieve it?

Thanks

[image: crank]

Edit:

At the end I would like to achieve a convex surface like the Vision Metron crankset has: [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this kind of object you should better work in a non-destructive way, it would allow you to easily change the shape, for example begin with this kind of mesh (mirrored with a *Mirror* modifier):

[image]

Give it an *Array* modifier:

[image]

And at the end give it a *Simple Deform* in *Bend* mode:

[image]

Continue to model, always keep a non-destructive version of your object so that you can go back if necessary.

You could also use the *Object Offset* option of the *Array* although the *Simpled Deform* is probably more flexible in this case.

For your final shape, extrude up the mesh, remove the inner faces:

[image]

If you want the round shape to be part of the same mesh, extrude up, extrude inwards:

[image]

Create some loopcuts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>:

[image]

Move them up to have your rounded shape:

[image]

If you plan to give it a Subdivision Surface, you'll need to bevel some edges:

[image]

Comment: After this, how would you make the teeth sharper ? So it is thicker at the circle and narrower at the teeth

Comment: Do you have a reference image?

Comment: Yes, I updated the post. Thanks!

Comment: @Mat I've edited, I hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

While you definitely should try to work non-destructively, on complex enough models you won't have the luxury. In that case, use transform orientations based on individual faces:

[image: animation]

.. using the very common combination of *Transform Orientation*: 'Normal' and *Transform Pivot Point*: 'Individual Origins'